# quick sort using partition

Tags: c++, quicksort, partitioning

I was trying to implement the quick sort algorithm using partitioning technique in C++.

The correct one is as below

```
template <class ForwardIt>
void quick_sort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    if (first == last) return;

    auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first, last) / 2);

    using pi = decltype(pivot);
    ForwardIt mid1 = myscope::partition(first, last,
        [pivot](const pi& em) { return em < pivot;});
    ForwardIt mid2 = myscope::partition(mid1, last,
        [pivot](const pi &em) { return !(pivot < em); });

    quick_sort(first, mid1);
    quick_sort(mid2, last);

}
```

However, I made a little change, which resulted in a wrong output. Below is my modified version.

```
template <class ForwardIt>
void quick_sort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    if (first == last) return;

    auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first, last) / 2);

    using pi = decltype(pivot);
    ForwardIt mid1 = myscope::partition(first, last,
        [pivot](const pi& em) { return em < pivot;});
    // ForwardIt mid2 = myscope::partition(mid1, last,
    //  [pivot](const pi &em) { return !(pivot < em); });

    quick_sort(first, mid1);
    // quick_sort(mid2, last);
    quick_sort(mid1+1, last);
}
```

So can someone help point out where the crux is.

---EDIT----

```cpp
namespace myscope {

template <class ForwardIt, class UPredict>
ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UPredict p) {
    first = std::find_if_not(first, last, p);
    if (first == last) return first;
    for (ForwardIt i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
        if (p(*i)) {
            std::iter_swap(i, first);
            ++first;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
};
```

Comment: Can you attach myscope::partition as well?

Comment: seems like [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682886/2425787) could be helpful.